# Task with forwarding time

Tags: python

I am having troubles completing a task.The task requires a user to put in time(between 1 and 12),then to declare if its am or pm, and how much hours to forward it to.The forwarded time should also show am/pm time stamp depending on how much is it forwarded.Example:

```
Input time: 8
am or pm : am
forward: 5
new time: 1pm
```

I have tried this:

```
time = eval(input('Input time(1-12):'))
ampm = eval(input('am or pm?'))
forward = eval(input('Forward:'))

if ampm == am:
    if time + forward > 24:
        new time = (time + forward)%24
        x = 'am'
    else:
        new time = (time + forward)%12
        x = 'pm'
    print('New time is:' , new time , x)

if ampm == pm:
    if time + forward > 12:
        new time = (time + forward)%12
        x = 'pm'
    else:
        new time = (time + forward)%24
        x = 'am'
    print('New time is:' , new time , x)
```

Comment: what error do you see?

Comment: Sometimes am and pm get messed up when i forward, for example when i forward 8am with 5h,i get 1pm which is okay, but when i forward 8am with 25h i get 9pm instead of 9am.

Comment: Where are `am` and `pm` defined? Did you check what the resulting value of `ampm` is when you run the program, and whether it evaluates as equal to `am` or not, and whether it evaluats as equal to `pm` or not? Did you perhaps mean to compare to the strings `'am'` and `'pm'`?

Comment: This cannot possibly be your real code; the repeated appearances of `new time` are all syntax errors.

Comment: Huh?This is my code,and i havent got a single syntax error,i only get wrong results since my code isnt right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest simply converting the time to 24h format, forwarding, then converting back to 12h(am/pm) format.

Here's how I'd do it:

```
time = int(input('Input time(1-12):'))
ampm = input('am or pm?')
forward = int(input('Forward:'))

# first get the 24h formatted time
time_24 = time + 12 if ampm == 'pm' else time

# then forward time to max 24, else start over from 0
time_24 = (time_24 + forward) % 24

# finally convert back to 12h(am/pm) format
time_12 = f'{time_24-12}pm' if time_24 > 12 else f'{time_24}am'

# print out the forwarded time
print(time_12)
```

Comment: i get an error when i try your code,it says time_24 is undefined when i set 'pm' on the input.

Comment: nvm i fixed it by replacing time_24 with just time everywhere.Thanks for the help though!

Comment: @Daxon I'd appreciate if you could upvote and accept answer :)

Comment: Aye no problem mate,i forgot to do it,my bad.